# Warning when starting an app [windows automation]

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, automation, scheduled-tasks

I have two . exe application that conflict eachother ( App_A and App_B).
I want to forbid the user from launching App_B when App_A is already running.
Here is the pseudo code :

```
if (app_A== Alreadyrunning) AND (App_B== TryingToLaunch):
    display ( Are you sure you want to launch App_B ? App_A is already running! Yes/ No)
```

ps: the display message must really open before App_B launch, not 1 sec after.

The user can try to launch App_B either from desktop shortcut of from a file binding. (user click on the file and it auto-launch App_B to edit the file.)

App_A and App_B aren't my software, I can't edit them. I think I must use an external automation software.

Does somebody have any idea on which software I could use ? 
I have tried **Window scheduler** with **batch file** (no sucess), but I am open to **any solution**.

Comment: Solved on another topic : http://superuser.com/questions/1017260/warning-when-starting-an-app-windows-automation/1017268?noredirect=1#comment1411986_1017268

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if a process is running using a batch script. For example, the following code would start app_b only if app_a is not running

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq app_a.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "app_a.exe">NUL
if not "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" app_b.exe
```

Comment: yes but if user double-click on a default-binded file, window will open App_B and not your batch script :(, so your solution  would be bypassed